# Add URL parameter value to input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have jQuery script that takes a URL parameter and adds the value to an input box.

When the URL is the form of `www.mysite.com/page/?number=10` everything works fine. When the url includes `.php` at the end of the page than the script doesn't work, e.g. `www.mysite.com/page.php?number=10`.

I need for the script to work with `.php` is used.

Here is the script:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    (function($) {
        jQuery.QueryString = (function(a) {
            if (a == "") return {};
            var b = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
            {
                var p=a[i].split('=');
                if (p.length != 2) continue;
                b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/+/g, " "));
            }
            return b;
        })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
    })(jQuery);

    jQuery.QueryString["number"];

    jQuery("#entry_2081224724").val(jQuery.QueryString["number"]);

  });
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Have you debugged to see where the issue is?

Comment: It doesn't work as in the parameter value does not get added to the input field. In Chrome, I receive this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat" but I don't know how to fix the expression.

Comment: Your regular expression is currently containing a quantifier `+` that means "1 or more" of the expression preceding it. But you mean the `+` literally, so you should escape it like so `\+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Your issue is, the regular expression character `+` gives an instruction to repeat the character that precedes it one or more times. The syntax error your getting is telling you that you haven't given it a character to repeat.

Are you trying to replace all `+` characters? If so, you're going to need to escape it with `\`.

Are you trying to say "one or more `/` characters"? Again, you'll need to escape that too, because `/` denotes the beginning of a regular expression.

Comment: I believe the OP is looking to replace the plus signs in the URL with spaces. So it should probably be `/\+/`.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Thanks for the help and the link to read up on regular expressions. That's definitely an area I don't experience in. Thanks again.